# How to close the process of another process?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, kill-process

I don't have so much experience in working with processes, so please be patient with me.

In VS I have a solution with 3 projects (proj 1, proj2, proj3).
I have 3 forms. Let's name them F1 (created in proj1), F2 (created in proj2), F3 (created in proj3). When a button from F1 is clicked, I start a process which opens F2.

```
 processExists = Process.GetProcesses().Any(yourProcess => yourProcess.ProcessName.Contains("F2"));

                if (!processExists)
                {
                    yourProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @".\F2.exe";                    
                    yourProcess.Start();
                    checkInterfata = false;
                }
```

When F2 apens I start another process which opens F3.

```
 processExists = Process.GetProcesses().Any(aProcess => aProcess .ProcessName.Contains("F3"));

                if (!processExists)
                {
                    aProcess .StartInfo.FileName = @".\F3.exe";                    
                    aProcess .Start();
                    aProcess = false;
                }
```

I am able to close F3 from F2 by killing `aProcess` when a Exit button is clicked. When I close F1, F2 is closed by killing `yourProcess`. I noticed that when I close F3, F2 is closed (which is OK) but without closing F3. What I have tried is to put on `F2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)` function the command: `aProcess.Kill();`  but with no success. How could I close aProcess when I close F1?

Comment: The requirement is that when F1 is closed, the other processes (yourProcess, and aProcess) must be closed. I managed to close yourProcess, but not also aProcess.

Comment: But why are you killing processes at all? This feels like a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is the way I found being used. What's the manner I should do correctly? How I mentioned, I didn't have so far the occasion to work with processes.

Comment: `[Process].CloseMainWindow`. I don't exactly understand why you're using the Process class for this.